# In signals processing why is the discrete sequence x[n] undefined (as opposed to 0) when n is not an integer?

Tags: notation, signal-processing

In Oppenheim & Schafer's "Discrete Time Signals Processing" it's written that:

... it is important to recognize that x[n] is defined only for integer values of n. It is not correct to think of x[n] as being zero when n is not an integer; x[n] is simply undefined for non integer values of n.

Comment: @ Mike For the sake of completeness, could you please define the notation  and terminology here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is by deliberate choice. So the answer to your question is "because the person who defined x(n) wanted x(n) to be defined only when n is an integer (and undefined for all other mathematical entities which n could possibly refer to)".

If you instead would like to know why this choice was made, the answer is: because x(n) is a sequence in the sense of x(0) is the first value x(1) the second, and so on. This well fits the data an (iterative) algorithm operates on/generates. So it is because a sequence is an adequate data model in the context of digital signal processing.